# Does Careers really *need* trackers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I use Ghostery and block most trackers by default, but I permit most JavaScript. Recently, visiting Careers has produced a Big Scary Overlay:

[image]

I'm aware that some poorly-written JavaScript breaks hard if analytics don't load, but are the trackers really necessary on Careers? Could the code be reorganized so that your particularly privacy-conscious user base doesn't get whacked by visiting with them disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was intended to only show up on the employer-facing part of the site, where large chunks of the site need a recent browser. It's not tracker related so I'm not sure why Ghostery would trigger it. I'll look into that soon. Regardless it shouldn't ever appear on the Stack Overflow jobs tab, so we've removed it from there.

Comment: I hope Firefox 45 is new enough! The only other blocker besides Ghostery is ABP, and I have SO whitelisted.

Comment: The banner shows for Firefox 46 and older, so that's why you saw it. Maybe that's too aggressive, but those releases -- except extended support releases -- are already unsupported by Mozilla. You shouldn't see the notice again since it's now just on the employer side.